# Java 8- total number of String deduplications in a multi-project build?

Tags: java, string, gradle, java-8

I am building a multi-project `java` application using `gradle`.

I am making use of the Java 8 *deduplication of strings* by adding the following flags to my `GRADLE_OPTS`:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+PrintStringDeduplicationStatistics
```

When my application is building I can see the output from `-XX:+PrintStringDeduplicationStatistics` multiple times. e.g:

```
[GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 2893.3K->2672.0B(2890.7K), avg 97.3%, 0.0175148 secs]
   [Last Exec: 0.0175148 secs, Idle: 3.2029081 secs, Blocked: 0/0.0000000 secs]
      [Inspected:           96613]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:           96598(100.0%)]
         [Known:                2(  0.0%)]
         [New:              96611(100.0%)   2893.3K]
      [Deduplicated:        96536( 99.9%)   2890.7K( 99.9%)]
         [Young:                0(  0.0%)      0.0B(  0.0%)]
         [Old:              96536(100.0%)   2890.7K(100.0%)]
   [Total Exec: 452/7.6109490 secs, Idle: 452/776.3032184 secs, Blocked: 11/0.0258406 secs]
      [Inspected:        27108398]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:        26828486( 99.0%)]
         [Known:            19025(  0.1%)]
         [New:           27089373( 99.9%)    823.9M]
      [Deduplicated:     26853964( 99.1%)    801.6M( 97.3%)]
         [Young:             4732(  0.0%)    171.3K(  0.0%)]
         [Old:           26849232(100.0%)    801.4M(100.0%)]
   [Table]
      [Memory Usage: 2834.7K]
      [Size: 65536, Min: 1024, Max: 16777216]
      [Entries: 98687, Load: 150.6%, Cached: 415, Added: 252375, Removed: 153688]
      [Resize Count: 6, Shrink Threshold: 43690(66.7%), Grow Threshold: 131072(200.0%)]
      [Rehash Count: 0, Rehash Threshold: 120, Hash Seed: 0x0]
      [Age Threshold: 3]
   [Queue]
      [Dropped: 0]
```

How can I see a *summary* of all the string deduplications for the full application, i.e. the *total effect* it has had on all the modules combined?

Comment: You won't be able to do this unless you modify how Java compilation is occurring. Since it's occurring independently on every subproject, you see the output for each subproject. You could write a task that parses this output and accumulates it, and have it depend on all of the subprojects' builds.

Comment: Why would you care? The string deduplication is a *runtime* feature, designed to affect the performance and memory footprint of the currently running application, not the application you are *building*. If want to know whether it is useful for the building process itself, use a stop watch and compare. Since everything is freed at the end of the building process anyway, the improvements regarding memory consumption are irrelevant as long as they don’t affect performance. If you want to improve the performance of your application, specifying these options to the building process makes no sense.

Comment: OK so when should they be specified then to improve performance?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this, and it is actually quite simple. The `TotalExec` block of the output is the total of *all* the separate string deduplication actions.

So in this case, the information relating to the total would be:

```
[Total Exec: 452/7.6109490 secs, Idle: 452/776.3032184 secs, Blocked: 11/0.0258406 secs]
      [Inspected:        27108398]
         [Skipped:              0(  0.0%)]
         [Hashed:        26828486( 99.0%)]
         [Known:            19025(  0.1%)]
         [New:           27089373( 99.9%)    823.9M]
      [Deduplicated:     26853964( 99.1%)    801.6M( 97.3%)]
         [Young:             4732(  0.0%)    171.3K(  0.0%)]
         [Old:           26849232(100.0%)    801.4M(100.0%)]
```

Comment: So the only remaining question is why you think that these number are helpful. As already explained, this is a *runtime* feature. Whether you specify it during the build process or not, has no influence on the application you are building. It’s only affecting the performance of the build process itself and that performance can be measured without that statistic.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it is only of use to monitor logs whenever the application is acutally running?

Comment: Right, when you specify these options when the application is actually running, it will have an effect on your application, but even then, you may monitor the actual overall memory consumption and speed to find out, whether it has a practical impact (and which). Of course, if you don’t see a change or get suspecting results, you may turn on the print statistics option for verification.